# VS Code: How to set WSL2 terminal to virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up a virtual environment for a project, which I did without much trouble using the command prompt terminal. However, if I open a second terminal but this time with Ubuntu (WSL2), it doesn't even have the same Python version. Probably it has to do with the virtualization of Ubuntu, but I'd like to know how can I have both terminals using the same virtual environment?

Pictures for reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's impossible.

In the first picture, you had got into the Linux system, so you can not take advantage of the python environment which in the windows system.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming I'd need to use a Git Bash terminal to access Linux commands such as ls and so on?